# Apache rewrite - catch and send to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Nothing I do seems to work. The last, stripped-down iteration I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /wiki/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

So far the most success I've accomplished:

- `/` doesn't route, but everything else does
- `/` routes, but nothing else does

Comment: In .htaccess. It's rough but at this point I'm just trying to get *something* to work like it's supposed to.

Comment: I'm trying to use clean URLs for a wiki on a subdomain in a last-ditch effort to use it without putting its files in the same directory as the main site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `/` from the start of the rule. For anything in apache 2+ the URI that is sent through rules in a directory based context (like in .htaccess), the leading slash is removed so `^/(.*)$` won't match anything:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wiki/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /wiki/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What's confounding is this is one of the combinations I tried and it didn't work, but in this case it does. It doesn't, however, still route to the PHP file if a directory exists, but this is satisfactory for my progress.